# Good location for Android Keystore?

Tags: android

Are there any guidelines for what the location of the Android keystore "should" be?   I'm ready to release my first app and in **Export Android Application** I'm creating a new keystore it wants me to specify the location.

FWIW my Eclipse Workspace is on a shared network drive and I access it from any of 3 different development systems.  I've had no problems doing this.   The default location that came up for the keystore location seemed to be in the SDK directory tree, but that won't work for me because each PC has its own copy of the SDK installed.   I need it to be in a location which can be seen from any PC that I might be doing development work from, so I assume that means the network drive or some virtual location in the cloud.

Are there guidelines, rules, restrictions or other things I need to know about the location  the keystore?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As long as it's somewhere safe (i.e. backed up remotely in source control or by some other method) it doesn't really matter. If you lose the keystore somehow then you'll no longer be able to update your app on the android market and will be forced to remove it and re-upload it as a new app signed with a new key.

If you're worried about security, remember that both the keystore and individual keys within it can (and should) be password protected.

My keystore is in the root of my android eclipse workspace, which is also the root directory of the git repository I use for version control. Seeing as you are developing on multiple machines and would potentially want to do a release from any one of them, I'd suggest doing the same.

Comment: What if your project is on Github?  It is safe to put the keystore in the root folder?

Comment: I guess it is since it's password protected. Iam doing the same with my public repos on github

Comment: If the source code is open, I don't think it's a good idea to commit it anywhere in the project (while it could stay there uncommited), because **sooner or later someone can decrypt/bruteforce the file** and its passwords. But if your code is not open and not published, then storing keystore in root directory or `app` directory is harmless as long as your repo is private and secure.

Comment: It's 2021 now, and you can store secrets like keychains in github-secrets :)

Comment: Since it's a binary file, and gh-secret is a text field, I did what lots of guides says - encoded it with base64, then decode it in the github-action script.

Answer (score 18):

I wish that github had a built-in tool to support storing the occasional private file for a public open source repo.  This is important for certificates and keystores that are associated with source code, but shouldn't be publicly viewable.

Ideally, github would have some sort of keystore repo that would act like a mini-private repo.  That way, you could put your private keystores in a private repo, and only share them with accounts who should be allowed to manage your Google Play and iTunes Connect accounts.

Until that day, I've taken to storing my keystore files in a free private repo on bitbucket, and then putting a link to the bitbucket repo in my github opensource repo.  That way, it won't get lost since anyone who can check out the source can see where the keystore is, but it also isn't publicly available.

Github, if you're listening, I think supporting a very restricted, free, private repo just for keystores would be a great service to the open source mobile app community.

Comment: GitHub gives a lot of stuff for free. You can simply buy access to the private repositories. Extra requirements equal additional price. It doesn't cost a fortune, but the quality of service is very good. That's how GitHub earns money. When they start giving everything for free, they can close their business.

Comment: Look up "github secrets"

Answer (score 13):

You want to keep your Keystore secure. If someone obtained it you essentially will lose authoring identity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html (bottom of page)

Comment: "If a third party should manage to take your key without your knowledge or permission, that person could sign and distribute apps that maliciously replace your authentic apps or corrupt them. Such a person could also sign and distribute apps under your identity that attack other apps or the system itself, or corrupt or steal user data." - I assume that's what you're referring to. (It's no longer at the bottom of the page.)

Answer (score 6):

I recently had the same question and looked online for different opinions. Most said store it remotely which is the obvious thing you want to do just in case your house or workplace burned down (you laugh but there are fire trucks for a reason). None really said where to store it remotely minus in the repo itself.

What I decided to do is create a google account for the android app (you should have one since you need it to publish through the playstore) then just use Google's free 15GB of space on Google Drive to store all of my keystores and anything else app related that i don't want to put in source control but I definitely don't need to loose. Maybe this will work for you and others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Since september 2017, you can have google store your keys for you by enrolling in App Signing: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/enroll-for-app-signing-in-google-play.html